upgraded to v 4.4.5 configuration path folder is missing
I have recently upgraded from 3.10 to 4.4.5.
My current php version is 8.1.24. I recently upgraded to this php version
My PHP information tab in Joomla System Information is showing the Configuration File (php.ini) Path as /opt/alt/php81/etc
When I follow the path, the final folder is not there.
The folder path I have is below. There is no etc folder within php81, so I don't seem to have a php.ini file.
Is this a known problem? How can I correct this please?
public_html

/home/

.cagefs

opt

alt

php81

link
var




php82




tmp
var






From what I have checked and read I would say that what you are seeing is okay and is not a problem, unless you are experiencing some related issue.
I have checked two different commercial hosting accounts and the both show the same/similar location for the configuration file as you have posted and yet following the file path there is no actual directory as you have found.
How I understand it from what I have read is that IF you wanted to specify or override one or more settings in your php.ini file then the directory you would place those 'user' changes is /opt/alt/php81/etc. As you have no directory or php.ini then your configuration is using the default system wide settings defined by your host.
